# Avoiding double traversal in outputting a L-shaped matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix, nested-lists

I am trying to traverse a list of Lists in *L Shape*. For example: `lShapedTraverse  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` will result in `[[1,2,3,6,9],[4,5,8],[7]]`

I have the following algorithm which gives the desired output:

```hs
lShapedTraverse :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
lShapedTraverse [] = []
lShapedTraverse [xs] = [xs]
lShapedTraverse (xs:xss) = let (rest, col) = ((map init xss), (map last xss))
                           in (xs ++ col) : lShapedTraverse rest
```

This is traversing the list of list 2 times to get `init` and `last`, which I think can be avoided using a custom function that can do `initAndLast` in one traversal.

I am trying to see if I can do a more efficient implementation and idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: How do you know that the current implementation is inefficient? What are your metrics?

Comment: What is the expected result if the sublists aren't all the same length? Maybe worth thinking whether "nested lists" is really the concept you're after; if it's actually "matrices" then there are packages for representing and manipulating them which *may* give you an easier time (and/or better performance) than working with nested lists that just happen to line up into a rectangle.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin It seems clear that OP wants to avoid traversing the list twice.

Comment: There are two close votes for this question on the grounds that it is _"likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations"_!? Sure, someone _might_ give a poor opinion-based answer, but that is true of any question on SO, and this one is certainly not worded in a manner that actively invites opinions. A good evidence based answer can surely show that there is (or is not) more efficient implementation without any "opinions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could write `initAndLast`, but it wouldn't help performance very
much because that would still be a lot of work to do for each element
of the result.

We really want to be working at the beginning of the lists so we can
get at the elements with only a constant amount of work.  We can
arrange this by flipping the matrix left-to-right with `map reverse`.
Now we always work with the first row and column.  We just have to
remember to un-reverse the row parts as we produce them.

```
-- L shapes from top left to top right then down to bottom right
lShaped :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
lShaped = lShaped' . map reverse

-- L shapes from top right backwards to top left then down to bottom left
lShaped' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
lShaped' [] = []
lShaped' ([]:_) = []
lShaped' (xs:xss) = (reverse xs ++ map head xss) : lShaped' (map tail xss)
```

We need the two base cases to deal with rectangles taller than they are
wide as well as wider than they are tall - your code is missing one
of these.

Alternatively we could try to use library functions rather than doing
manual recursion.

This function slices a rectangle into two parts along an upward-sloping line.  `n` is
the length of the first row of the upper/left part, or if n is greater
than the width of the rectangle you have to imagine it as a coordinate
outside the rectangle defining the top-right point of the cutting
line, so that some full rows will appear in the upper/left part before
we get down to the cut.

```
slice :: Int -> [[a]] -> ([[a]], [[a]])
slice n xss = unzip (zipWith splitAt [n,n-1 ..] xss)
```

Using slice splits up the elements nicely for the horizontal and
vertical parts of the Ls, but the vertical parts aren't arranged in a
useful way.  Rather than try to rearrange them we can use slice again
on the transpose of the matrix to get them in the right lists.
Finally we put the horizontal and vertical parts together with
`zipWith (++)`.

```
lShaped'' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
lShaped'' [] = []
lShaped'' xss = zipWith (++) rowParts (reverse colParts)
  where
    (rowParts, _) = slice width xss
    (_, colParts) = slice width (transpose xss)
    width = length (head xss)
```

I don't know if I like this solution better than the manual recursion
but there it is.  It's always a bit of a shame to introduce lengths
and numbers into a list algorithm but I don't see a cleaner way at the
moment.

Answer (score 0):

As there are several possibilities to represent the input matrix, we can try to separate the “navigation”, i.e. choice of elements, from the actual matrix representation.

In order to achieve this, we can easily write a recursive function that produces the 2D list of Cartesian coordinates to be extracted from the input matrix:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  TupleSections        #-}

-- returns 2D list of Cartesian coordinates for entries of L-shaped matrix:
coordList :: Int -> [[(Int,Int)]]
coordList n = go n 0 n  where   -- rl: Row Length   sr: Starting Row
    go n sr rl = ((map (sr,) [0..(rl-1)]) ++ (map (,rl-1) [(sr+1)..(n-1)]) )  :
                  if (rl > 1)  then  go n (sr+1) (rl-1)  else  []
```

Checking under the `ghci` interpreter:

```
 λ> 
 λ> coordList 3
 [[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)],[(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)],[(2,0)]]
 λ>
```

Next, we test our new `coordList` function by naïvely using the inefficient !! list extraction operator:

```
 λ> printAsLines xs = mapM_  (putStrLn . show)  xs
 λ> 
 λ> xss = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines $ map (map (\(i,j) -> ((xss !! i) !! j))) $ (coordList 3)
 [1,2,3,6,9]
 [4,5,8]
 [7]
 λ>
```

This might be inefficient, but it is correct. And so we can have a more efficient version of this by replacing lists by vectors and the list !! operator by the equivalent vector ! operator:

```
import qualified  Data.Vector as  V

-- vector-based version:
lShapedTraverse :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
lShapedTraverse xss = 
    let
         rank   = length (head xss)  -- matrix rank
         pairs  = coordList rank     -- 2D list of Cartesian coordinates
         matrix = V.fromList (map  V.fromList  xss)  -- 2D vector
    in
         map  (map (\(i,j) -> ((matrix V.! i) V.! j)))  $  pairs
```

### Test program:

```
printAsLines :: Show α => [α] -> IO ()
printAsLines xs = mapM_  (putStrLn . show)  xs


main :: IO ()
main = do
    let  xss   = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
         lMat1 = lShapedTraverse  xss

    putStrLn $ "res1 = "
    printAsLines lMat1
```

### Program output:

```
res1 = 
[1,2,3,6,9]
[4,5,8]
[7]
```